# How to run bluecove in ubuntu?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bluetooth, ubuntu-16.04, bluecove

I have installed bluecove by adding those two library in IntellJ:

`bluecove-2.0.2.jar` and 
`bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar`

and I ran the sample code provided in bluecove:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.bluetooth.*;

/**
* Minimal Device Discovery example.
*/
public class RemoteDeviceDiscovery {

public static final Vector/*<RemoteDevice>*/ devicesDiscovered = new Vector();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    final Object inquiryCompletedEvent = new Object();

    devicesDiscovered.clear();

    DiscoveryListener listener = new DiscoveryListener() {

        public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
            System.out.println("Device " + btDevice.getBluetoothAddress() + " found");
            devicesDiscovered.addElement(btDevice);
            try {
                System.out.println("     name " + btDevice.getFriendlyName(false));
            } catch (IOException cantGetDeviceName) {
            }
        }

        public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {
            System.out.println("Device Inquiry completed!");
            synchronized(inquiryCompletedEvent){
                inquiryCompletedEvent.notifyAll();
            }
        }

        public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
        }

        public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
        }
    };

    synchronized(inquiryCompletedEvent) {
        boolean started = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().getDiscoveryAgent().startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, listener);
        if (started) {
            System.out.println("wait for device inquiry to complete...");
            inquiryCompletedEvent.wait();
            System.out.println(devicesDiscovered.size() +  " device(s) found");
        }
    }
}

}
```

I got the following stack error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library 
 /tmp/bluecove_androidweardev_0/libbluecove.so which might have 
 disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
 It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c 
 <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
 Native Library bluecove not available
 Exception in thread "main" javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove not available
at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:271)
at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.access$100(BlueCoveImpl.java:64)
at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl$1.run(BlueCoveImpl.java:502)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStackPrivileged(BlueCoveImpl.java:500)
at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.getBluetoothStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:489)
at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.<init>(LocalDevice.java:64)
at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDeviceInstance(LocalDevice.java:71)
at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDevice(LocalDevice.java:86)
at RemoteDeviceDiscovery.main(RemoteDeviceDiscovery.java:44)
```

I've installed libbluetooth-dev, blueman and bluez but none seem to make it work, I'm out of options.

I' m also looking if there a bluetooth SIG official example using bluetooth-low energy with java.

Any advice or tip is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Seems there is a known issue with 64-bit systems. Please try workaround (running in 32-bit mode) provided here: https://github.com/yihtserns/bluecove/issues/35

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the main problem is the `bluecove-2.0.2.jar` doesn't match the `bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar` version.

I replace the `bluecove-2.0.2.jar` to `bluecove-2.1.0.jar`.

everything works now.